# Search a collection of TabItems for a TabItem Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to input the name of a TabItem to a Window containing a TabControl that contains a collection of TabItems, programatically search the collection and open the TabItem with the name that matches that input.  dkozl answered a similar question Aug 16 '13 but I don't understand it (I'm new to this).

I've kicked this around for a couple of days and have come up with the following (which doesn't work)

```
foreach (IEnumerable<TabItem> item in tabControlList)
{
    if (item.Name == "AddRskAreas")
    {
        item.IsSelected = true;
    }         
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tab not found");
    }
}
```

I struggle to understand how to implement IEnumerable. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: _doesn't work_ is the most useless explanation that you can give of a problem. When you go to a car repair shop do you tell them "It doesn't work" ? Please explain what is the error received from the code above and add more context to this foreach. What is and how is declared and intialized the variable _tabControlList_ ?

Comment: You should also look at debugging, put a breakpoint inside your loop.  Look at what the value of item.Name is.  Look at all the values on item.  This is how I found out that the name of the tab was in the "Header" property.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input .  I've arrived at a working solution and posted it below in case anyone else can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I derived a solution with a little help from Sean Sextons 2,000 Things You Should Know About C# knowledge base.  I'll post the key XAML and C# fragments of my solution below in case anyone else can piece them together get value from it.

Interestingly the buttons are now faded out - anyone know why?

//The XAML fragments ....

```
    <!-- These RoutedUICommands (in <Window.Resources>) are bound to the Process Procedure Selection Buttons.  Clicking on the button 
    opens the corresponding process procedure TabItem  -->
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="OpenPrcdrTbItm" Text="This Command opens the Process Procedure TabItem"/>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <!-- These CommandBindings (in <Window.CommandBindings>) bind the Process Procedure Selection Button Commands to the Command Handler in the code behind  -->
    <CommandBinding Command = "{StaticResource OpenPrcdrTbItm}" Executed="RskPrcssPrcdrs_Click"/>

    <Button x:Name="ChngeRskAreas" Grid.Column="1"  Content="Change Risk Areas"
    Command ="{StaticResource OpenPrcdrTbItm}" CommandParameter="ChngeRskAreas"/>
```

//The C# code behind fragments

```
    //Select the chosen TabItem 
    public void RskPrcssPrcdrs_Click(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RskManWndw rskManWndw = new RskManWndw(this);      //Instantiate a new rskManWndw window
        TabControl tabControlCollection = new TabControl();
        TabItem tabItemCollection = new TabItem();
        string slctdTabItem = (string)e.Parameter;
        bool slctdTabItemFnd = false;
        string msgBoxMsg = "";

        //Open the rskAraManWndw window
        rskManWndw.Show();
        foreach (TabItem tabItem in rskManWndw.RskManPrcssTbCtl.Items)
        {
            if (tabItem.Name == slctdTabItem)
            {
                tabItem.IsSelected = true;                          //Select the chosen TabItem.
                slctdTabItemFnd = true;                             //Flag that the TabItem was found.
                break;
            }
        }
        if (slctdTabItemFnd == false)                               //Was the TabItem found?
        {
            msgBoxMsg = "A TabItem matching the" + slctdTabItem + "Command Parameter was not found.  "
                      + "Please inform the system administrator.";
            MessageBox.Show($" {msgBoxMsg}", "RMS Processing Error Alert");
            rskManWndw.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Hide();                                                     //Hide the Risk_Management_System.MainWindow
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update multiple values in a list using LINQ:

```
tabControlList.Where(item => item.Name == "AddRskAreas").ToList().ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually compare the "Header" instead of the name.

```
foreach (IEnumerable<TabItem> item in tabControlList)
{
    if (item.Header== "AddRskAreas")
    {
        item.IsSelected = true;
    }         
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tab not found");
    }
}
```